# Design pattern for 2 varities of the same feature

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, software-design

All,

I am developing a feature that will on execution of an operation write the logs to a file server using ftp. Note that the write to file server will happen only if a file server is configured. If no server is configured the operation will exit and return the status. The flow is something like this:

1. Execute operation
2. If file server connected (check in DB and ping), write logs
3. return

Now I would like to know if there are design patterns for this, same feature, however the scope of the feature will vary depending on whether or not some configuration is done. I would much appreciate help on this for 2 scenarios:

1. Static - If the DB config is one time during boot up - as in post bootup the system can "assume" that the file server is there or not based on the read from DB
2. Dynamic- When the system is up and running, I might bring up a file server and configure DB. Ideally for this scenario the system should detect the file server and start writing logs to it, rather than being forced to reboot the system.

Requesting help in this regard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design looks like a breach of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You are entangling two different concerns: the first concern is the operation itself, and the second is shipping the logs to a central location.

Think about separating your component into two simpler, independent components. One of them performs the business operation and writes logs, say to a local file, and that's it. The other component checks for the existence of new logs on the local file system and copies them to the central location.

Comment: Thanks, the input solved my problem! Redesigned to ensure single responsibility principle

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention whether or not you are using an existing logging framework, such as Log4J.  If not, it would probably be a good idea - if you try to roll out your own logging framework, you can end up having to deal with additional unforeseen complexities, such as dealing with log levels (INFO, DEBUG, ERROR, etc.).

With regards to your original message - I'd consider using the [Factory](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-factory) pattern - create a factory class that can internally check whether the file server is available, and return one of two different logger types - something like a ConsoleLogger and an FTPLogger.  Make sure that both of these implement the same interface so that your calling code doesn't have to care about what type of logger it's using.  Alternatively, you can also use a [Decorator](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-decorator) that can wrap the object performing your operation - and once it completes a request, have the decorator do the logging.

A final comment - try to avoid checking whether the file server is available every time that you log.  A database hit on every log call could result in horrible performance, not to mention that you'll have to ensure that errors in the logging method (such as DB locks) don't result in your entire operation failing.